# Loading a dropdown content dynamically

Tags: dropdown, odoo

I'm new in the Odoo world and now I'm stuck. I have this (Odoo v11.0):

```
Model: class Dog()

  dog_name = fields.Char()

  gps = fields.Many2One(Model Gps)

Model: class Gps()

  serial = fields.Char()
```

I have a Gps list that is show in the Dog's form as a dropdown list, each time a Dog record is created only one Gps can be assigned to it, so the next time I create a Dog those assigned Gps must not appear in the dropdown list.

How to accomplish it?
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add below method in class Gps.

```
@api.multi
def name_get(self):
    if self._context.get('filter_gps'):
        gps_records = self.env['Dog'].search([('gps','!=',False)]).mapped('gps')
        new_self = self - gps_records
        return super(Gps,new_self).name_get()
    return super(Gps,self).name_get()
```

Comment: Thank, it works as I expected inside dropdown list but now the Dog list (tree) does not show the gps neither in the form view. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Please set context in dog form view where gps field is written.
For example, 
<field name="gps" context="{'filter_gps':True}" />

Than change in name_get method as per above update.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to Dog class:

```
@api.one
@api.onchange('gps')
def onchange_gps(self):
If not self.gps:
    Res = {} 
    Ids = [] 
    Dogs = self.env['dog'].search([]) 
    Ids = [d.gps for d in dogs] 
    Res['Domain'] = {'gps' : [('id', 'not in', ids)]}
    Return res
```

Comment: I changed some parts of the code and worked ok, `ids = self.env['dog'].search([]).mapped('id')`. In edition all gps are shown, is there a way to filter them too?

Comment: What is the eval of Res?